# Generate the start and end ranges for a specific JavaScript Date and identifier (month, day, year, week)?

Tags: javascript, date

Is there a way to intelligently find the beginning and end times of a specific Date object in JavaScript for a certain time window (month, day, year, week)?

I'd like to be able to give it any date, then an identifier (like month, week, day, or year), then a boolean for whether or not it should use UTC time. It should return a JavaScript object with two keys (startTime, endTime) where the values for these keys are the epoch milliseconds (or date objects) representing my range.

I began writing a function to do this (see below), just wondering if there is a smarter way to go about doing it:

```
/**
 * @param rangeValue; String ('year', 'month', 'week', 'day')
 * @param dateTime; JavaScript Date Object.
 * @param useUTC; Boolean. Determines whether or not UTC is to be used or default browser time
 * @returns {{}}; startTime and endTime, in epoch milliseconds
 */
function generateTimeRange(rangeValue, dateTime, useUTC) {
  var dateRange = {};

  var year = dateTime.getUTCFullYear();
  var month = dateTime.getUTCMonth();
  var dayOfWeek = dateTime.getUTCDay();
  var day = dateTime.getUTCDate();

  if (!useUTC) {
    year = dateTime.getFullYear();
    month = dateTime.getMonth();
    dayOfWeek = dateTime.getDay();
    day = dateTime.getDate();
  }

  if (rangeValue === 'year') {
    dateRange.startTime = new Date(year, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
    dateRange.endTime = new Date(year + 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).getTime() - 1;
  } else if (rangeValue === 'month') {
    dateRange.startTime = new Date(year, month, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
    month += 1;
    if (month > 11)
      year += 1;
    dateRange.endTime = new Date(year + 1, month % 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).getTime() - 1;
  } else if (rangeValue === 'week') {
    // Do week calculation
  } else if (rangeValue === 'day' {
    // Do day calculation
  }
  return dateRange;
}
```

EDIT: Just discovered that Moment.js has `startOf` and `endOf` methods. Is there an elegant way to do this without external libraries?

Comment: Before you do "start of" and "end of" you need to define what they are. E.g. ISO weeks start on Monday, US weeks usually Sunday. End of week might be Sunday (ISO), Saturday (US) or Friday (western business week). Some cultures have a business week from Saturday to Wednesday or Thursday, with Friday being the equivalent of western Sunday.

Comment: Note that in `new Date(year, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` the day value should be 1, otherwise you'll get 31 December the previous year. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably more suitable in a code review forum.

It doesn't seem sensible to get all the UTC parts, then see if you need them and get local parts if not. Just get the ones you want. And since UTC should be used everywhere if required, then:

```
var UTC = useUTC? 'UTC' : '';
```

Now you just do:

```
var year = dateTime.['get' + UTC + 'FullYear']();
var month = dateTime.['get' + UTC + 'Month']();
```

and so on. But there's no need to do those unless you must. Then there's:

```
if (rangeValue === 'year') {
```

that is pretty strict, you might want it case–insensitive so:

```
if (/^year$/i.test(rangeValue))
```

then

```
dateRange.startTime = new Date(year, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
```

will get 31 December of the previous year since you've set the date to 0. It will also be 00:00:00 for the host system timezone, not UTC (if it was specified). If you only provide the year and month, all the other values are zero (except for date, it's 1) by default, and you want to use UTC if specified so:

```
dateRange.startTime = (UTC? new Date(Date.UTC(year,0)) : new Date(year,0)).getTime();
```

Similarly for end time:

```
dateRange.endTime = (UTC? new Date(Date.UTC(+year+1,0)) : new Date(+year+1,0)).getTime() - 1;
```

You actually don't need *getTime* since the subtraction will coerce the value to a number anyway, but it keeps things consistent. To do month is similar:

```
// Get the month
var month = dateTime['get' + UTC + 'Month']();
// If month range is required
if (/^month$/i.test(rangeValue)) {
  // Get the start of the month
  var monthStart = UTC? new Date(Date.UTC(year,month)) : new Date(year,month);
  // Assign the time value
  dateRange.startTime = monthStart.getTime();
  // Adjust to end of month.
  // The setTime method returns the time value, so no need for getTime
  dateRange.endTime = monthStart['set' + UTC + 'Month'](monthStart['get' + UTC + 'Month']() + 1, 1) - 1;
  return dateRange;
}
```

So putting that part together:

```js
function generateTimeRange(rangeValue, dateTime, useUTC) {
  var dateRange = {};
  var UTC = useUTC? 'UTC' : '';
  var year = dateTime['get' + UTC + 'FullYear']();

  if (/^year$/i.test(rangeValue)) {
    dateRange.startTime = (UTC? new Date(Date.UTC(year,0)) : new Date(year,0)).getTime();
    dateRange.endTime = (UTC? new Date(Date.UTC(year+1,0)) : new Date(year+1,0)).getTime() - 1;
    return dateRange;
  }

  var month = dateTime['get' + UTC + 'Month']();
  if (/^month$/i.test(rangeValue)) {
    var monthStart = UTC? new Date(Date.UTC(year,month)) : new Date(year,month);
    dateRange.startTime = monthStart.getTime();
    // The setMonth method returns the time value, so no need for getTime
    dateRange.endTime = monthStart['set' + UTC + 'Month'](monthStart['get' + UTC + 'Month']() + 1, 1) - 1;
    return dateRange;
  }
  // Add week, day, etc.
}

var dr = generateTimeRange('year', new Date(), false);
console.log('Start: ' + new Date(dr.startTime) + '\nEnd: ' + new Date(dr.endTime));

dr = generateTimeRange('month', new Date(), false);
console.log('Start: ' + new Date(dr.startTime) + '\nEnd: ' + new Date(dr.endTime));

// UTC tests, note if west of GMT will seem to be one day early:

dr = generateTimeRange('year', new Date(), true);
console.log('Start: ' + new Date(dr.startTime) + '\nEnd: ' + new Date(dr.endTime));

dr = generateTimeRange('month', new Date(), true);
console.log('Start: ' + new Date(dr.startTime) + '\nEnd: ' + new Date(dr.endTime));
```

Comment: Thanks @RobG! I ended up taking a look at how Moment.js implements their `startOf` and `endOf` functionality [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/moment/start-end-of.js). They use a switch case where they set each individual unit as it falls through the statement. Your method is a little nicer for my use case, I didn't know you could dynamically run functions within square brackets like that.

Comment: Functions are Objects, so you can use square bracket notation for property access just like any other Object. :-)